# Linq orderby on multiple columns with one potentially null

Tags: linq

I have a table with 2 fields in it: [Name] and [Order]

[Order] can be null

Using LINQ, I'd like to be able to order by [Order] or if [Order] is null then order by [Name]

here is my non-working code:

```
from ft in FacetTypes
orderby ft.Name, ft.Order ascending   
select ft
```

Is this possible in linq?

EDIT:

[Order] is int?
[Name] is string

The query is an Entity Framework 4 one.

ANSWER:

This is what I eventually got to work.

```
ft.Order == null ? ft.Name : SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)ft.Order)
```

Comment: What's non-working about your code? What result do you expect?

Comment: What is `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean if `Order` is null for a single element, use `Name` instead? If so, I *think* you want:

```
from ft in FacetTypes
orderby ft.Order ?? ft.Name
select ft;
```

This is just using the *null-coalescing operator* introduced in C# 2.

Comment: Cheers. Just tried it. Error says: "Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type int? and string.

Comment: Have to add SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)ft.Order)

Comment: Cheers for everyones help. This is what i used: "ft.Order == null ? ft.Name : SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)ft.Order)"

Comment: @sf: Right, it wasn't clear what the data types were before. Glad it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var resultSet = 
     ft.Order == null ? 
          FacetTypes.OrderBy(item => item.Name) : 
          FacetTypes.OrderBy(item => item.Order);
```